# How to configure Spring beans against two Data sources with same schema

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to write a DB sync utility with Spring JPA, where in I have a Source DB and Target DB, having same schema. How do I reuse the Entity objects, Repositories? Currently I am running into issue with a repository bean not being able to be instantiated as it is already associated with first (Source) datasource.

I believe , @Profile cannot be used here , as the Source and Target beans have to co-exist.

Appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create several data sources with Spring.

```
@Configuration
public class JpaConfig {
    
    @Bean(name = "source")
    public DataSource h2DataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:file:C:/temp/test");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("sa");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "target")
    @Primary
    public DataSource mySqlDataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("dbuser");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("dbpass");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

Then, you can get the datasources from the Dependency Injection. You can name them `source` and `target` so you can keep track of them.

```
@Qualifier("source")
DataSource source;

@Qualifier("target")
DataSource target;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution to your issue with some theoretical background to make understanding easier. Comes with a working example on Github.

I suggest you clone the repo, get it to run and work and then copy the necessary pieces of the code.

https://reflectoring.io/flyway-spring-boot-multitenancy/